# how to write a constraint in a table for sybase to reject all empty strings update and insert?

Tags: constraints, sybase

I am trying to write a constraint to stop adding or updating the value of any column with empty strings.
i could only think of doing it this way
create table test_table 
( mystring1 varchar(10) null,
  mystring2 varchar(10) null,
  constraint no_empty_string_constraint
  check( mystring1 <> "" or mystring2 <> ""))

is there a smarter way to do this? that says for all column with type varchar <> "" ?

Answer (score 0):

What about char columns as well - you might want to consider those. You could do a lookup from systypes which will give you a list of char/varchar columns for that table:

```
 select c.name from syscolumns c, sysobjects o where c.id = o.id and o.name = '<tablename>' and c.type in (select type from systypes t where t.name in ('char','varchar'))
```

You should then be able to include that in a constraint.